# Where does this error come from? Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am unable to figure this out. I have added my keyhashes and all to the Facebook webpage but I am unable to figure out this error

```
11-12 19:51:27.744: D/HelloFacebook(5188): Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this exception when my Facebook app is in Sandbox Mode but logged in and try to post status by a user who not included in developer list. You may check your developer roles or disable the Sandbox Mode.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem and got its solution by putting Application name into `FacebookDialog`. So here is the solution

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
    .setLink("https://www.google.com")
    .setApplicationName("name of app")
    .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

It works for me!

Comment: FacebookDialog shows error. Which library version do you use ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and in my case, I was missing an entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file i.e.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: This fixed it for me on a Xiaomi MI 5! The weird thing is it worked without this fix on all other devices.