# Facebook share from android app

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to add sharing from an android app to facebook.

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
            .setLink("https://www.google.com")
            .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

It manages to open the share window but closes it right away with

```
com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name.
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I tried to sign my app in to facebook and created a facebook app and even made it public (though besides the fact that in the facebook app I put in my android app's package and main class I don't know how to link the two - I don't know how to use the facebook app id if I'm suppose to).
Thanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/

Comment: Byzantine Failure I'm not sure what you are referring to, I don't see how that link helps, can you please tell me what section you were referring to?

Comment: I found the solution and I feel a little stupid though nowhere told me to do this.
The solution is to add .setApplicationName("TheRealRace")

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(activity)
            .setLink("https://www.google.com")
            .setApplicationName("TheRealRace")
            .build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

Comment: Duplicate?: [Where does this error come from? Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Failed to get app name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19943807/456814)